# My work revolves a lot on CR. Why does my crystal reporting process freeze?

Tags: .net, service, crystal-reports, report

My work revolves a lot on CR. Why does my crystal reporting process freeze - at this time no crystal reports on the application will render anything?

It works back and fine when system is restarted temporarily, or running some windows resource as admin? Using CR on Visual tudio 2019.